# Controling the size of dropdown button in p:autoComplete (primefaces)

Tags: jsf, autocomplete, size, primefaces, drop-down-menu

I'm using primefaces 3 in my jsf 2 web application to show a list of suggestions :  p:autoComplete

```
 <p:autoComplete
     value="#{articleBean.unite}"
     completeMethod="#{articleBean.autocompleteUnite}"
     var="item" itemLabel="#{item.code}" itemValue="#{item}"
     converter="#{articleBean.uniteConverter}" 
     dropdown="true"/>
```

the attribute dropdown="true" adds a dropdown button next to the input item :

the problem is the size of the dropdown button : it looks huge and I can't change it's size.

is there a style class that controls its appearance of may be style element, please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-right ui-button-icon-only"         type="button" style="**width: 100px;**">
 <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>
 <span class="ui-button-text"></span>
```

'ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-right ui-button-icon-only' this class may help you.

Comment: based on your response I looked for the class that controls autocomplete dropdown in primefaces :
It's **ui-autocomplete-dropdown** in **autocomplete.css**  

.ui-autocomplete .ui-autocomplete-dropdown {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 16px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 0 3px;
    margin-right: -24px;
}

how can I overwrite this behaviour and change it's values?

Answer (score 0):

In your page copy this code into `<head>`:

```
<style>
button.ui-button-icon-only {width: 1em} 
</style>
```

I hope that works for you.

Comment: Will be better to copy this to CSS ;-)